# Multiple property Full-Text Search with MongoDB in Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5.1

I am using MongoDb with laravel.

Below is my users collection sample json data

```
{
    "_id" : "52dfcd17daf02a2e6cb396c7",
    "email" : "nikhil@gmail.com",
    "name" : "Nikhil"
}
{
    "_id" : "52e0f9a2daf02ac908064f68",
    "email" : Michael@gmail.com,
    "name" : "Michael"
}
```

I have created index for 2 columns in collection, which is name & email.
(email can be null)

```
db.users.ensureIndex({'email':'text', 'name': 'text'})
```

When I search for name I get the exact search data but when i search exactly for an email id it gives all the records.

Here is my code

```
$users = Users::whereRaw(['$text' => ['$search' => 'Michael@gmail.com']])->paginate(20);

return response()->view('users.view',
[
      'users' => $users,
      'title' => 'Search results for your query: ' . $query
]);
```

Comment: you should give a data sample and the unexpected result.

Comment: In much agreement that saying "goes wrong" doesn't really explain a problem. You also have some terminolgy wrong as *"email Id record"* means what? Perhaps you mean just the "email" field/property? In that case, you didn't ask it to only return that field, so why should it. Also noting that you are "paging" ( in likely some horrible library way that you should rethink ) without actually "sorting" the results. That's a real problem, particularly with a "text search", where typically people expect results "sorted" by relevance. Which you have not done, and MongoDB does not do this for you.

Comment: Also. This smacks of yet another mistaken identity for using `$text` where you really should be using `$regex` queries with an `$or` condition for each possible field. Text searches should be used for words, synonyms and "phrases". It's not a drop in replacement for exact or partial matches on multiple fields.

Comment: Hello Blakes, correct email is a property.  I was just trying to display the data so once it works i will integrate it with sort concept which is needed but for me it was failing initially itself when i was trying to get the records based on email and name.

Comment: I tried using Users::where('name', 'regex', new MongoRegex("/.*".$query."/i"))->get(); but I get Class 'App\Http\Controllers\MongoRegex' not found